# Azure B2C Custom Policy Social Button Showing Above Local Account Fields

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

I have added social logins to out custom policy.  I am using the latest version of unifiedssp
urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:unifiedssp:2.1.8

For some reason the div containing the social buttons are appearing above the local login, whereas if I use the same page version with a user flow the social buttons appear below the local login.

I have since used default B2C pages - Classic and Azure Blue, i.e.

```
  <ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted.unifiedsigninsignup">
    <LoadUri>~/tenant/default/unified.cshtml</LoadUri>
    .....
```

I find that classic puts the social buttons above the input form and Azure Blue below.

Is this controlled by something in the HTML or CSS/JS as I thought we were not meant to alter the order via JS.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I am having the same issue when using custom html file.